# IDP Initiated SSO not working in spring security SAML sample app

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

I have a fork of spring security saml project. You can see the changes I've applied here: https://github.com/troyhart/spring-security-saml/commits/nwri-sample_simple.

The SP `urn:troyhart:nwri` is registered at SSO Circle. If you have an SSO Circle login you can fire up the application and test that SP Initiated SSO works. However, I can not get IDP Initiated SSO to work. I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error determining metadata contracts
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:91)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Metadata for issuer http://idp.ssocircle.com wasn't found
  at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:108)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:77)
  ... 29 more
```

What's strange is that the exception indicates that the sample application thinks the IDP EntityID is `http://idp.ssocircle.com`, but the real EntityID for SSO Circle is `https://idp.ssocircle.com`.

Does anyone know what's going on here? The thing that is strange is that I have tested that IDP initiated does work, but at some point it stopped working and now it fails every time with the given exception. Please help! I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the [quick-start quide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/docs/reference/docbook/quick-start.xml) references a deprecated `metaAlias` in the documented IDP-initiated SSO URL for SSO Circle. The new value is `/publicidp`.

The URL should therefore be:

```
https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/publicidp&amp;spEntityID=replaceWithUniqueIdentifier
```

I've submitted a pull request for the fix.